# What is the term for "a" and "an"?

Tags: grammar

What is the technical term for the words "a" and "an" as in:

> a Banana
>   an Elephant

and does the rule for using "an" in front of words that begin with a vowel have a name?

Comment: Are you looking for *determiner*?

Comment: Or more specifically *indefinite determiner*. The second question is intriguing. I wonder if there is a name.

Comment: @AndrewLeach the answer to the intriguing question is [Sandhi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandhi), in order to avoid [hiatus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiatus_%28linguistics%29). Sadly going by the accepted answer the OP is not really interested in the answer to the intriguing question, but rather in the answer to the basic question that can be looked up in any dictionary. Closing as general reference. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/an#English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [indefinite determiner](http://www.englishpower.eu/en/ep-free-lessons/elementary/determiners/some-and-any) can refer to "some" or "any", [indefinite article](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/indefinite-article-and) refers specifically to "a" or "an".